# How to filter dbaccess output in Informix?

Tags: database, shell, informix

I want to run `dbaccess <dbname> <sqlfile.sql>`, and store the output to a shell variable. I know there are two methods to do (i) output to pipe and (ii) unload to file. I want to use method (i) kind of approach to store the query output to a shell variable, but along with the query output I am getting unwanted things (connected to database, column headings, disconnected) — see the image attached. I don't want to use method (ii) because I need to store query output to a shell variable, not a file. Please help me with this.

[image: all the data which is going to shell variable I have attached]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, not the best for some cases is sending **stderr** to `/dev/null`.

Let's create a table to test it:

```
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ dbaccess demo -

Database selected.

> CREATE TABLE starc (col1 INT, col2 INT);

Table created.

> INSERT INTO starc VALUES (1,1);

1 row(s) inserted.

> INSERT INTO starc VALUES (2,2);

1 row(s) inserted.

>

Database closed.

[infx1210@tardis ~]$
```

For one column and one row, ore more, this is quite enough:

```
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ out_1r1c=`echo "select col1 FROM starc WHERE col1 = 1" | dbaccess demo 2>/dev/null | uniq`
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ echo $out_1r1c
col1 1
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ out_2r1c=`echo "select col1 FROM starc" | dbaccess demo 2>/dev/null | uniq`
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ echo $out_2r1c
col1 1 2
[infx1210@tardis ~]$
```

For more than one column, probably not the best option:

```
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ out_1r2c=`echo "select * FROM starc WHERE col1 = 1" | dbaccess demo 2>/dev/null | uniq`
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ echo $out_1r2c
col1 col2 1 1
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ out_2r2c=`echo "select * FROM starc" | dbaccess demo 2>/dev/null | uniq`
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ echo $out_2r2c
col1 col2 1 1 2 2
[infx1210@tardis ~]$
```

**Follow up question**

For what you're doing simple pass the information on the `eco` command to a SQL file script and execute it.

For example:

```
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ echo "CONNECT TO 'sysmaster@infx1210' USER 'starc' USING '${PASSWD}'; SELECT USER FROM sysdual;" | dbaccess -

32412: USING clause unsupported. DB-Access will prompt you for a password.
Error in line 1
Near character position 45

[infx1210@tardis ~]$ finderr 32412
-32412  USING clause unsupported. DB-Access will prompt you for a password.

DB-Access does not support the USING password clause in a CONNECT ...
USER statement when it violates security. For example, do not type a
password on the screen where it can be seen or include it in a command
file that someone other than the user can read. To maintain security,
DB-Access prompts you to enter the password on the screen and uses echo
suppression to hide it from view.


[infx1210@tardis ~]$ echo "CONNECT TO 'sysmaster@infx1210' USER 'starc' USING '${PASSWD}'; SELECT USER FROM sysdual;" > file.sql
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ dbaccess - file.sql 2>> test.log


(expression)

starc
[infx1210@tardis ~]$
```

I don't like this approach. You should consider using [SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1189.htm?lang=en) statement.

Now for a user to use it **DBA** database level privilege must be granted and, also, **SETSESSIONAUTH** access privilege is required, and only a user who holds the [DBSECADM](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sec.doc/ids_lb_029.htm?lang=en) role can grant the **SETSESSIONAUTH** privilege, and only a [DBSA](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sec.doc/ids_au_046.htm?lang=en) can grant the **DBSECADM** role for a user.

Normally the members of the **OS** group that owns the **$INFORMXIDR**/etc are **DBSA**, in this case:

```
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ ls  -ld $INFORMIXDIR/etc
drwxrwxr-x. 5 informix informix 4096 May 18 13:33 /opt/IBM/informix/V12.1/etc
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ grep informix /etc/group
informix:x:501:ricardo
[infx1210@tardis ~]$
```

So, besides the **informix** user only **ricardo** is a member of **DBSA.** Let's stick with **informix** for simplicity.

The next step is to [GRANT the DBSECADM](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sec.doc/ids_lb_006.htm?lang=en) role for **informix**, this is a special role that will spread across all databases, you don't have to do it one by one:

```
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ echo "GRANT DBSECADM TO 'informix'" | dbaccess sysmaster

Database selected.


DBSECADM granted.



Database closed.

[infx1210@tardis ~]$
```

Now, the **SETSESSIONAUTH** cannot be given to the user itself, so let's give it to **ricardo**:

```
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ echo "GRANT SETSESSIONAUTH ON 'starc' TO  'ricardo'" | dbaccess demo

Database selected.


SETSESSIONAUTH privilege granted.



Database closed.

[infx1210@tardis ~]$
```

Switching to the user **ricardo**, remember that it should have **DBA** privilege, we can now:

```
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ echo "SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION TO 'starc'; SELECT USER FROM systables WHERE tabid = 1;" | dbaccess demo 2>>/dev/null


(expression)

starc

[infx1210@tardis ~]$
```

Comment: thanks a lot @henriques , it was so nice of you as always and really useful.

Comment: hi , In ( out_2r2c=`echo "select * FROM starc" | dbaccess demo 2>/dev/null | uniq` ) why we are using "2>" and I am not getting output when I include (connect to db@instance user 'un' using 'pwd' ;)in query by removing "demo" from dbaccess  dbname 2>... i.e, I want to know if we can connect as user and execute the query ? please elucidate my doubt.

Comment: The `2>/dev/null` will redirect **stdout** to bit bucket, that means if you're getting an error you will not see it. Change it to `2>>query.err` to redirect it to an actual file and see the error on it. After that change show the actual command you're passing. and the error on the file.

Comment: @henriques , found an error "32412: USING clause unsupported. DB-Access will prompt you for a password.Error in line 1" , is there any way to execute a query in the above way you said and including connect to 'db@server' user '$username' using password '$password' , I mean connect to database as a user and execute query on behalf of that user ?

Comment: @starc check the **follow up question** section.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by [Ricardo Henriques](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4667815/ricardo-henriques) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37187982/15168), you can do a certain amount by redirecting standard error.

Also consider the [OUTPUT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0926.htm) statement:

```
OUTPUT TO "/dev/stdout" WITHOUT HEADINGS
    SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE …
```

or the [UNLOAD](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1248.htm) statement:

```
UNLOAD TO "/dev/stdout"
    SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE …
```

Using `"/dev/stdout"` is a trick — a useful one on occasion.  You can specify any file name there.  You may still want to redirect errors.  Be aware that DB-Access blunders on after errors — you can stop it doing so by setting `DBACCNOIGN=1` in the environment.

Also, consider checking out [SQLCMD](https://www.iiug.org/en/iiug-software-repository/#ESQLl) which I wrote because it behaves in shell scripting contexts and DB-Access doesn't.  It dates back to 1986 (before there was `dbaccess`; in those days, you used `isql` instead — DB-Access was carved out of `isql` in an evening).  The current version is SQLCMD 90.00 (2015-11-08).  It bears no relation to Microsoft's johnny-come-lately program of the same name — except for the name.

Comment: tried both methods suggested by you and @henriques both are working, you both always inspire me and drive me to learn informix.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to the previously stated, to first output the STDERR to null then grep -v for $^.

IE, select the current date and time from the database:

```
$> echo "output to /dev/stdout without headings select first 1 current from systables;" > query.sql
$> FOO=`dbaccess mydb query.sql 2>/dev/null | grep -v "^$"`
$> echo $FOO
2017-07-27 14:25:30.000
$>
```

You just need to make sure your query returns one row, one column only.